# Rails: Multiple references to the same model error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have a **Message** model that has a **user** and a **teammember** (both are users). 
The models are:

```
# message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :teammember, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'teammember_id' 
end

# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end
```

And I have this migration:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :teammember, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.text :body
      t.boolean :read, default: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the **rake db:migrate** locally (with sqlite3) everything works fine.
The problem is that when I deploy to heroku (that uses postgresql) and run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It raises the next error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "teammembers" does not exist
>   : ALTER TABLE "messages" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_7efc67ccc9"
>   FOREIGN KEY ("teammember_id")
>     REFERENCES "teammembers" ("id")

Do you know what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails guesses based on the association, because you're referencing a table it can't determine from the association you'll have to add it yourself.

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :teammember, index: true
      t.text :body
      t.boolean :read, default: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :messages, :users, column: :teammember_id
  end
end
```

Comment: As an addition to the answer, there were no complaints on the OP local machine running `sqlite` since rails sqlite adapter does not support foreign_key (so totally ignored the problematic part), only mysql & pg adapters do http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support